# Where to put data range filter in aggs query for ElasticSearch server?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to get doc counts within a certain date range from an ElasticSearch server. The query is use is:

```
# Build ID query
body = {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "unique_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id.keyword",
                "size": 1000000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now have to add a time range filter in there, but after trying several things, I'm still getting nowhere. Always get errors that my query is wrong. Where do I put the filter? I figured the key I have to add should look something like this:

```
 'filter': {
     'bool': {
         'must': {
             'range': {
                  'startTime': {
                        'format': "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                        'gte': '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000',
                        'lte': '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

On a side note, I'm really not a fan of how these queries have to be put together. Very counterintuitive, at least to me.

EDIT: This was one of my failed attempts:

```
{
    'aggs': {
        'unique_id': {
            'aggs': {
                'filter': {
                    'bool': {
                        'must': {
                            'range': {
                                'startTime': {
                                    'format': "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                                    'gte': '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000',
                                    'lte': '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            'terms': {
                'field': 'id.keyword',
                'size': 1000000
            }
        }
    },
    'size': 0
}
```

Comment: Maybe share the errors you get

Comment: Afraid they don't say much:  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'unknown_named_object_exception', 'Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [bool]')

Comment: I'd like to see your full query, not just piece of it

Comment: I tried several things, I'll update the question with one attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
           'filter': {
              'range': {
                   'startTime': {
                       'format': "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                       'gte': '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000',
                       'lte': '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'aggs': {
        'unique_id': {
            'terms': {
                'field': 'id.keyword',
                'size': 1000000
            }
        }
    },
    'size': 0
}
```

Comment: Dude, you absolute legend, that's twice now that you fixed my broken-ass query. Thanks!